# Twig loop gets mutliplied

Tags: symfony

Lets say I have some data called 'brands ' in an array past into a twig template like this:

```
{ 0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,6:7,7:8}
```

Second array called 'designs' like this

```
{120:11,123:22,189:32,300:34,400:53,500:63,688:37,799:28}
```

o/p excepted

```
12,24,35,38,59,70,45,36
```

the below code shows what i have tried and the o/p  expected for 8 times, but i am getting 64 times the output like

```
{% for key ,value in brands %}
  {% for key,design in designs  %}
// for example i need to add the value and design for 8 times
 {% set total = value + design  %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's 8 times 8? 64!

Comment: yup i know.. i am new to twig... so i have no idea to implement a break statment @sjagr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly nesting your loops, and adding each element of `designs` to each element of `brands`. You only need one loop:

```
{% for key, value in brands %}
    {% set total = value + designs[key] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Don't forget you can't access `total` unless you define it before starting the loop:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for key, value in brands %}
    {% set total = value + designs[key] %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you're looking for the sum of both of the arrays into one `total` with varying numbers of elements for `brands` and `designs`:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for key, value in brands %}
    {% set total = total + value %}
{% endfor %}
{% for key, value in designs %}
    {% set total = total + value %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you're looking to add together each corresponding element between `designs` and `brands` without depending on matching keys - it's a much more difficult process when trying to do it in Twig, and you're missing what Twig is meant for entirely. You should handle this data in the controller or build a better data model to pass to Twig. For example:

```
$brands = array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>3,3=>4,4=>5,5=>6,6=>7,7=>8);
$designs = array(120=>11,123=>22,189=>32,300=>34,400=>53,500=>63,688=>37,799=>28);
$brands_designs = array();
foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
    $design_key = key($designs);
    $brands_designs[$key] = array(
        'brand' => $brand,
        'brand_key' => $key,
        'design' => next($designs),
        'design_key' => $design_key
    );
}
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Folder:template.html.twig', array('brands_designs' => $brands_designs));
```

Then in your Twig template:

```
{% for key, value in brands_designs %}
    {% set total = value.brand + value.design %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if you insist on matching each element together and adding them individually...

```
{% for brandKey, brand in brands %}
    {% set outerLoopIndex = loop.index %}
    {% for designKey, design in designs %}
        {% if outerLoopIndex == loop.index %}
            {% set total = brand + design %}
            {# do stuff with total here, like {{ total }} #}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above isn't tested, I'm a little worried about variable scope in there. It actually iterates a total of 64 times with your sample set but only outputs on the diagonal (when the outer index == inner index, so `1 == 1`, `2 == 2`, etc.)

Comment: suppose if the key in the second for loop is different??

Comment: @dude Well you don't have a very good data model to work with here. What exactly are you trying to achieve? The sum of both of those arrays?

Comment: i have done it... my keys is different in the second array as i getting it from my controller... i will give the correct data model

Comment: @dude I can see that, but **what are you trying to achieve**? Do you need the sum of all of the array values? Or do you need the sum of each pair of values? What is your expected output?

Comment: but according to your code it just adds the last value to it.. i need to add like 1 and 11,,please see my edited data model

Comment: @dude If Twig had the PHP `next()` function available that would be possible but without that it's much more difficult. Usually would involve rebuilding both of the `brands` and `designs` into key-less lists for Twig to iterate through one and access the other by the same key. You should be handling the more complicated stuff in your controller (see my edit) and leaving Twig to do the lighter stuff... it only needs to show things. Don't make it do the heavy lifting.

Comment: fine will try and let u know sjagr

Comment: @dude Left you with one more example so you can see why it's just not a good idea to do this in Twig.